# how to backup all salesforce metadata

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to figure out the best way to backup all of our Salesforce metadata in our full sandbox.

We've had a large team working on numerous areas of Salesforce (configuration and development) and we've promoted all that code to our full sandbox.  Before moving to production, we want to backup all the metadata.  We are not concerned about actual data.  We just want to make sure we backup all the metadata in our full sandbox, then promote to our production instance and finally do a refresh of our full sandbox.

We thought about using a change set, but that would be horribly tedious, time-consuming and would it indeed grab all metadata.

Would creating an unmanaged package be an option?  I've never done anything with packages, so I'm in the dark on that process.  Would it be easy to grab all the metadata?

I've read about options using the ANT Tool, which I have no experience using and it seems to be a little tricky to setup and configure.

I use Eclipse regularly, I don't believe Eclipse can grab all the metadata (approval processes, etc.)?

Any insight and help on solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest using a [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). It's the best way for managing all changes into your project, store history of changes and comfortable team work. I prefer [git](http://git-scm.com/) but you can select any other.

For managing changes which can't be retrieved via Eclipse/ant migration tool or any other tool I use file named "NonMetaDataChanges" which stores all configuration steps which should be performed on fresh org for setup application before and after deployment of metadata. usually these manual changes takes no more than half a hour.

Also I've just checked that Approval Process can be retrieved via Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the easiest way to create a metadata backup to create or refresh a sandbox?  Other than custom settings, what will it miss?  With the sandbox change-sets could be create to return production to a happier place.

The best path, I agree, is to put all changes under version control.  But until all metadata can be extracted and re-imported, some kind of all-of-the-above approach must do.